# How to document argument label and not parameter name of Swift function in XCode?

Tags: swift, xcode, markdown, documentation

I know how to document the parameter name of a function like:

```
/**
 - parameters:
   - param: the parameter
 */
func myFunc(param: Int) {...}
```

but I am unable to document the argument label (either with or without the parameter name):

```
/**
 - parameters:
   - label: the label
   - param: the parameter
 */
func myFunc(label param: Int) {...}
```

After all, documenting the label is more important than the parameter name, as it is what is used at function calls.

Note: I've been unable to find the trick in Apple's documentation, or I did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot directly refer to the argument label** in the documentation of a function.

As a workaround, you can mention the label in the description of the parameter, like this:

```
/**
 - parameters:
     - param: (argument label: `label`) the parameter
 */
func myFunc(label param: Int) {...}
```

With the usage of back-ticks, it blends in nicely with the parameter itself:

[image: example function documentation]